# Writing some javascript comment on scripts using grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I want to use grunt to automatically write some JavaScript comments like Author Name, Version etc. at the top of all script file.

Answer (score 3):

Would something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437620/dynamically-add-version-number-to-dest-output-files-w-grunt) work? Seems like you'd be inserting some placeholder text at the top of each file.