# How do I clear cached angularjs files

Tags: html, angularjs, caching

I have an angularjs based web application with some functionality deployed to users that I need to hide.  I've added the code to hide it and successfully verified the controls are hidden when appropriate but there are still users who have the old version of the file and can perform the undesired activities.  Is there a way I can control from the server the view file to refresh on the client?  (The tester was able to clear their cache but it's a burden to the users in the field)

Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to version the files. For example, the following line in your `index.html`

```
<script src="abc.js" />
```

could be rewritten as

```
<script src="abc.js?v1" />
```

`v1` is the current file version and should be changed for each deployment of your application when `abc.js` has changed.

Since `index.html`(the initial page) is obtained from the server, updations to `abc.js` will now be reflected on all your clients.

This would need to be automated in a huge application. You could use Grunt for this. You can refer the following answer on StackOverflow for automating this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20446748/802651

**UPDATE** 
HTML views/templates are cached using $templateCache in AngularJS. Basically, when you request templates for the first time, browser requests the template from the server and puts it in the template cache. Any subsequent requests to the same template are served from the template cache.

If you do not want these to be cached, you could listen to the `$routeChangeStart` event inside `app.run` block to remove the specific templates.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

Reference: http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.in/2014/02/safely-prevent-template-caching-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Thanks Adarsh, that's a good suggestion for js files - I'm actually working on the view/.html side, those seem to get really out of date unless I tell the customer to clear their cache or give them paths to go out and refresh individual html pages.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm going to try this this weekend and see how it goes next week.